# How to draw this circular nodes at desired center?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

Here I am drawing circular nodes at (0,0) in my document. I need to draw these nodes at the desired centre. An example at (8,-6.5). 
Can anyone help me to generate code to draw multiple circular nodes in one page at desired center?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
        \draw (\x:5cm) circle (1mm);
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need circular nodes with the centre of (8,-6.5).

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
        \draw ([xshift=8cm,yshift=-6.5cm]current page.north west)+(\x:5cm) circle (1mm);
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`?

Comment: You realize that the picture will be positioned relative to the bounding box, not the coordinates.  If you are planning to add other elements, that is one thing.  Moving the picture relative to the page is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the easiest way to apply a shift to a bunch of points.  It also adds the origin to the bounding box, and draws the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(8,-6.5)}]
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
        \draw (\x:5cm) circle (1mm);
    };
  \end{scope}
  \path (0,0) node[circle,draw] {Origin};% add origin to bounding box (and label it)
  \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can position the stuff at an absolute coordinate using `overlay,remember picture`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
        \draw ([xshift=8cm,yshift=-6.5cm]current page.north west)+(\x:5cm) circle (1mm);
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
        \draw ($(current page.north west)+(8cm,-6.5cm)+(\x:5cm)$) circle (1mm);
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo Really? This is absolute page positioning using the `current page.north west` anchor. Your statement applies to overlay pictures that do not use absolute page coordinates, I think.